# PhpStorm change Emmet-end-div-comments to being a PHP-comment

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

Is it possible to change Emmet-end-div-comments (enabled in `Preferences >> Editor >> Emmet >> enable 'Comment tags'`) so it doesn't make HTML-comment, but making a PHP-comment instead?

So if I type:

```
div.foobar
```

and press `tab`, that it then expands it to being

```
<div class="foobar">

</div> <?php //.foobar ?>
```

instead of

```
<div class="foobar">

</div> <!-- /.foobar -->
```

For a cleaner source-code in production...

Comment: no, it's not possible, comment generated by this filter is not customizable; you can try creating a custom [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/live-templates.html) instead

Comment: Is it a big job making a plugin that'll do it, perhaps?

Comment: Emmet is all about HTML and CSS and has well described syntax (https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/) which PhpStorm follows. Creating a custom live template is the easiest thing and you already can do this in PhpStorm.

Comment: But can I do it, so that every time I make a div-tag, that it automatically adds the PHP-comment? Do you have an example of, how that Live Template would look like - and/or how it would work?